# output of NDSolve is the initial condition of other NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve two sets of differential equations where the output of the solution of the first set of differential equations, at the end of the evolution of the equation, is the initial condition of the other set.

Maybe the code will describe it better. I just tried different ways to get M1[t] at the end but I could not.

```
sol = NDSolve[EquationsWithInitialConditions, {M1[t], M2[t]}, {t, tstart, tend}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/10000, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];

{M1[t], M2[t]} = {M1[t], M2[t]} /. sol[[1]];

initial1 = {M1[0] == Evaluate[M11[t], t -> tend]}; (*This does not work*)(*This should be the initial condition equation of another NDSolve*)
```

Note that: M1[t] comes in the shape as follows. where tend is `1.2*^-9`
[image]

Comment: I would like to get the numerical value of M1[[tend]]. This is a simpler way to define the question

Comment: @xzczd or `(M1[tend]/.sol)`?

Comment: @ChrisK Oops, that won't work, my (now deleted) previous solution won't, either. OP needs e.g. the following: `{M1[t_], M2[t_]} = {M1[t], M2[t]} /. sol[[1]]`, then `M1[tend]`.

Comment: Another solution is to modify all of the `{M1[t], M2[t]}` in your code to `{M1, M2}`.

Comment: It would be nice if `EquationsWithInitialConditions` were defined.

Comment: Thank you for trying to solve it. Based on the below answer `M1[0] == M11[t] /. t -> time` was helpful and fixes it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume this is the first equation:

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 2.3*x[t] - 0.1 x[t]^2, x[0] == 1}, 
  x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

from the simplified theory of coronavirus:

```
    Plot[x[t] /. sol1, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["t", 16, Italic], Style["x", 16, Italic]}]
```

[image]

Let us take its solution in the time moment `t=1` as the initial condition for the second equation and entitle it `ini`:

```
ini = (x[t] /. sol1[[1]] /. t -> 1)
```

Let the second equation be simple linear oscillator equation:

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{u''[t] == -u[t], u[2] == ini, u'[1] == 0}, 
  u[t], {t, 1, 10}]
```

Let us plot it:

```
Plot[u[t] /. sol2, {t, 2, 10}, PlotRange -> {-20, 20}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["t", 16, Italic], Style["u", 16, Italic]}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I guess I was looking for `M1[0] == M11[t] /. t -> time`

Thank you so much that was helpful, you're the best :)